# Jquery nestable plugin item click event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am using jquery [nestable](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable).
Everything works fine except one thing: I want to add mouse click event on each item like below:

```
   <li class="dd-item" data-id="1" onclick="doWork();">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
   </li>
```

and my code java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doWork() {
     alert('clicked');
   }   
</script>
```

But it's not working. There's no syntax error. It seems the plugin is disabled or I have miss-configured something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plugin, the html might be generated dynamically by plugin after DOM load so use [**delegated events**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
 <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
   </li>
```

and in jquery:

```
$(document).on("click",".dd-item",function(){
     alert("clicked");
})
```

Comment: yes i did it.my code includes some other functions sticking with some html element and all of those work fine except event above.i dont know why.i see firebug,there's no error bro.

Comment: It doesn't work because nestable messes with the on click event to work with collapse button

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it with:

```
var clickData = {};
$(document).on('mousedown', '.dd-dragel > li', function(e){
    clickData.timer = (new Date()).getTime();
    clickData.x = e.pageX;
    clickData.y = e.pageY;
}).on('mouseup', '.dd-list .dd-item', function(e){
    let n = (new Date()).getTime() - clickData.timer;
    if(clickData.x === e.pageX && clickData.y === e.pageY && n < 200){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
});
```